# Redhat user account password expiring after 15 days instead of 30

Tags: passwords, redhat-enterprise-linux

My user account on a Redhat 5.10 box is set to have my password be changed every 30 days however, it forces me to change the password every 15 days instead.

I have confirmed the setting by doing the `chage -l <username>` command and the "Maximum number of days between password change" is set to 30 days. I am not sure what else to check has anyone had to deal with this?

Comment: To help everybody help you please show the appropriate security file that sets the date of the expiration.

Comment: when you say "it forces me to change the password every 15 days instead", you mean this happened more than once ? 
Indeed, the "max days" counts from last password change, not from the moment chage command was entered.

Comment: I am actually not the System Admin so I don't think I have access to that security file unfortunately. Yes it seems to happen every 15 days.  What will happen is that I will go to log in and my password has expired so I have our administrator issue a password change for me. Then again in 15 days the password expires without warning.